# Android Studio - Bad CPU on brand new MacBook Air M1

Tags: android-studio, apple-m1

This is the first application I installed, so there should't be anything to screw up Android Studio.
I tried a number of BumbleBee and Arctic Fox versions, being careful to choose the Apple Silicon version, but none of them work out of the box.
I get the error: "Cause: error=86, Bad CPU type in executable"

The emulator runs, but is of no use since I can't run the app. There's no option to to connect via USB and the "pair new device over wifi" just gives me an "unexpected error".

Anyone know what it takes to get this beast working?

Answer (score 0):

Gave up on this eventually, so moved on to next application "Xcode".

During the installation I was asked if I wanted to install Rosseta, which is a dynamic translator to enable Intel based software. I didn't think it was necessary because I installed the Apple Silicon version of Android Studio, but did it anyway.

It turned out to be what was missing to get Android Studio to work. While running an app, the adb service is listed as kind "Intel" in the activity monitor.

In fact, now that I got Flutter up and running, bot Dart and Java is also listed as "Intel", so at the moment there doesn't seem to be full support for running Flutter on M1 chip.

Even so, it runs pretty fast, and I guess it will be even faster when there's full support for M1.